# what is error message 'GradleDependency'?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I have problem in android studio kotlin
message is
 Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Could not get unknown property 'GradleDependency' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

```
     buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.70'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()


    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
         classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()


    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

what is solution ?

Comment: Post the build.gradle file that has this unknown `GradleDependency` property in it

Comment: No Answer?.......

Comment: This looks like the top-level build.gradle and nothing out of the ordinary there. The problem could be in your app module's build.gradle.